# Java Method Overloading Best Practice

Tags: java, methods, overloading

Just wondering what is best practice where creating to methods with the same signature

case 1

```
public void transfer(Department department){
    this.department = department;
}

public void transfer(Department department,String postion){
    this.department = department;
    this.postion = position;
}
```

Case 2

```
public void transfer(Department department){
    this.department = department;
}

public void transfer(Department department,String postion){
    transfer(department);
    this.postion = position;
}
```

Comment: why would one be different from the other? but this is just one case: what if the method with only one param needs validation on department that the other doesn't need? sometimes it is possible to do it like this. other times it is not. Especially if it only serves to replace a single line of code: what's the use?

Comment: You may also have the first method call the second one (with some default value for `position`), and the second one assign both values.

Answer (score 8):

You avoid code duplication.

From that point of view, option 2 is slightly better, as it prevents the repetition of that assignment. Typically, you do that with constructors, and then you call it *constructor telescoping*. To get to real telescoping here, you should follow the advice from Berger and rather have the one argument method call the two-argument method. That **also** communicates to the reader what setting *just* the Department actually leads to.

Beyond that: the real problem I see here is naming. `transfer()` implies that something gets transferred. In reality, your method is nothing but a **setter**. It should be named accordingly, like `setTransferDetails()`.